# A park seat or a car seat has two main parts. One part is the back. What is the name of the other part?

Tags: single-word-requests

A car seat or a park seat has two main parts. One part is the back, against which one leans their back. What is the name of the part that one actually sits on (puts their buttocks on it)? For a chair these two are called back and seat respectively. But what about a car seat or a park seat?

Comment: I would use the same. _Please wipe the seat before you sit_ - PS: I have never heard of a park seat? I call it a park bench

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I believe @mplungjan is right. One can call the part in question, "The seat of a car seat". About the park seat as you mentioned the correct term is "park bench". And then again one can refer to the lower part as "the seat of a park bench".

Comment: For a car, I would call it 'the seat bench'. I think that would be clear. For a park seat, I'd call it a park seat. Or park bench seat. As distinct from a park bench back.

Comment: To me "the seat bench" only makes sense with bench seating; for cars which have 2 separate front seats (e.g. sports cars), it's less appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

In general upholstery usage, the squab is the thickly padded cushion of a chair or sofa one sits upon, contacting the thighs and buttocks.

In North America and Europe, Squab in Vehicles is the lower seat portion.

The exception is England for automotive usage during the 1900s. In that context, squab refers to the backrest portion of the chair or side supports one may lean against.  In England today, if the conversation is about antique cars or purchasing parts for them, squab refers to the backrest.  If the conversation is about modern cars or their parts, squab refers to the seat bottom portion. If clarity is desired, the term squab is avoided.

- Eg. archaic; for old Austin mini parts www.7ent.com uses squab for
  the back.

  Eg. modern; Oxford Dictionary Online (ODO) uses squab for the seat
  bottom in three examples of modern usage.

  Eg. Clarity; MINI Market-UK.com avoids any reference to a squab

  Eg. Confusion; Oxford Dictionary Online gives the definition as the
  padded back of a vehicle seat, then gives three examples referring to
  the SEAT BOTTOM portion. An internal contradiction! Note: the three
  examples are recent sentences in the context of modern automoboiles.

Answer (score 2):

One word for a the part of a car seat that you sit on is ***squab.***

> 1
>   a :  couch
>   b :  a cushion for a chair or couch
>
> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/squab)

> That centre front seat slides all the way back until it hits the rear-seat squab, so a child can still sit ‘in the front’, but remains sufficiently rearward not to be hit by an airbag designed to restrain an adult.
>
> [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/squab)

The word isn't applicable to a park bench because generally they aren't cushioned. I've only seen it used in reference to car seats, although dictionaries imply that it can be used of any seat cushion. It's not normally used for the back cushion (even though ODO does mention that).

Comment: When I was in my motor mechanics apprenticeship, at a Ford main dealer, the seat base, the part you sit on, was always referred to as 'the squab' and the part you leaned back on was the 'back'.

Comment: When I drove motor coaches, in the 1980’s, the part you sat on was always described as the _squab_.

Answer (score 2):

I  found a diagram illustrating a car seat and its components for a [Programmable seat back damper patent](http://www.google.com/patents/US6601915)

The cushion where the driver or passenger sits on is either  called a *horizontal cushion* or *seat cushion*. The back of the car seat (No.16) is called the *seat back* but it can also be referred to as a [***backrest***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/backrest).
*A support for a person’s back when they are seated*  <sub>Oxford Dictionaries</sub>

[image]

> The **seat 12** includes a generally **horizontal seat cushion** portion
>   or **seat cushion 14** and a generally upright seat back portion or
>   **seat back 16** pivotally connected to the **seat cushion 14** by a seat back pivot 17. The seat cushion 14 includes a seat pan (not
>   shown) and a **cushion 18** operatively connected to the seat pan by
>   suitable means such as an adhesive. The seat back 16 includes a seat
>   back frame (not shown) and a cushion 20 disposed about and operatively
>   connected to the seat back frame by suitable means such as an
>   adhesive. (...)

Perhaps the OP was thinking of a *bench seat* of a car when he mentioned a *park seat*. It is a term which I was unfamiliar with, so  I decided to include it anyway.

[image]

> **[Bench seat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bench_seat)**
>   The bench seat was the traditional seat installed in American and
>   Australian automobiles. This seat featured a continuous pad running
>   the full width of the cabin. The second row of seating in most sedans
>   is usually a bench. The third row of most SUVs and minivans, which may
>   be forward, or rear facing is also a bench seat.

<sup>Source: Wikipedia</sup>

Answer (score -1):

My father grew up in the family motor business which was founded in Southern England before he was born in 1910. He always referred to the sitting-on part of a motor seat as the squab.

@Mari-Lou A, many larger British cars of (at least) the 1950s and 1960s had a front bench seat, though I don't think that's what the OP was referring to. ,